# How to parse response from this jsonp call (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to make a JSON call to an external site (which I have no control over) in order to retrieve a pricelist. It's a simple call:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://www.external-site.com',
type: 'GET',
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: {SelectedObjectId:"742",DeliveryOptionId:"2",CountryId:"4",SelectedExtensionId:"-1"},
success: function(response) { console.log('succes: ' + response); },
error: function(response) { console.log('error: ' + response); }
});
```

When I look in the Chrome developer tools, I see a response is returned with all the information I expect. However the 'succes' status is not returned, instead the 'error' function is executed and when I log the response, I end up with an object that does not seem to be the same as the json response I see in the developer tools. How do I retrieve and work with the response that shows up in developer tools? I'm inexperienced with ajax calls and did a lot of searching and trying different things but none have worked in this particular case.

Edit: I removed the JSfiddle and the link to the external site in order to prevent potential strain on their server.

Comment: It is a cross domain request.. and it looks like the said API is not supporting either CORS or jsonp

Comment: so the solution is to use your server as an proxy and make the ajax request to your server then from your server request the remote data and return the value returned by the remote request to the client

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. It's unfortunate that Chrome fails to point out this cross-domain issue, but it makes sense that this is the cause of my problem. I will try the proxy approach, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arun P Johny's comments above I was able to solve this issue by making the ajax request to a simple proxy.php on my server, which in turn fetches the external site and returns the data that I need.

I used this tutorial on how to set it up: http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/10/cross-domain-ajax-a-simple-workaround/